# Bluetooth adapter disconnects randomly. (NOT just devices.)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

First of all, let me list all my specs.

ASUS ROG GL752VW

Intel core i7 6700 @ 2.6GHz

Windows 10x64

16GB RAM

Now my problem: my Bluetooth adapter seems to disconnect randomly and I have no idea why.  Sometimes it will go months without ever disconnecting, and sometimes it disconnects and goes months without even working.  The little icon disappears from my taskbar, and I am unable to use Bluetooth.  My computer reports that I don't have bluetooth.  I am not sure of the exact adapter but I do know it is Intel and that they are together.  I never ever have any issues with WiFi however Bluetooth is just causing me all sorts of hell.
I've tried all of the following things, so please don't suggest them...

Rebooting.  Tried it multiple times

Reinstalling the drivers.  With and without rebooting.

Uninstalling the device from Device Manager and reinstalling it.

"Repair"ing the driver from the installer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It disconnects randomly.  I want it to NOT disconnect randomly.  Again, I am not talking about devices connected via Bluetooth, I'm talking about the bluetooth adapter itself